# How to Use robot_localization

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working in a project, where I have to use Robot Position.

IMU unit is attached with that, Now I found [Robot_Localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package, which I can use in my project.
I dont have any GPS device with robot and I dont know  How to use this and  what are the setup requirements before using this package.

Can I use Mobile as GPS device over Robot? If yes then How to Integrate with ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200212/how-to-use-robot_localization/) by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-12-30**:
This sounds like two questions. One is about using a mobile device as a GPS, and the other is about using robot_localization. I would suggest making them two separate questions.

Also, can you give us more details? Does your robot have odometry?

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-12-30**:
Yes It sounds like 2 ques but I found GPS integration in Robot_localization package, That is why I asked, What will happen If I wont use GPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your IMU is going to give you, at most, orientation, angular velocity, and linear acceleration. An IMU alone is not going to be sufficient for navigation. If you do have wheel encoders that are producing velocity or position and an IMU, then you're in good shape. Read through the `robot_localization` [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) page and tutorials for information on how to set it up. You can also look at the sample launch files in the source code repo. You shouldn't have to make any code changes, no.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-12-31**:
I am trying this, I will ask help again. But one more question is this package specific for any robot or can be used in any robot. I am using [FIREBIRD VI Robot](http://www.nex-robotics.com/products/fire-bird-vi-robot/fire-bird-vi-robotic-research-platform.html)

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-12-31**:
It's meant to be used for any robot. I'm not familiar with the Firebird, but if the data all conforms to ROS standards, robot_localization ought to work with it.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-14**:
can you plz tell me how to execute these. I am creating node that will publish /odom topic,
is ekf_template.launch is enough for getting pose info?  how to write publisher node for Imu?

**Comment by [el loco](https://answers.ros.org/users/44756/el-loco/) on 2019-08-27**:
If, per se, I was interested in speed (not even necessarily velocity) but not position, would an IMU be enough hardware to use with this package? I'm trying to find how to use this package and can't find any clear examples. Thanks in advance

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-08-31**:
An IMU only provides rotational velocity. It doesn't provide linear velocity or speed. The double integration of linear acceleration will make your state estimate unusable within a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Android mobiles you can install "[ROS Sensors Driver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ros.android.sensors_driver&hl=en)" from play store. then you will have a node that running in your mobile and publishing the sensors topics.
I used the mobile acceleration sensor to control the pioneer robot. Check this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/iPhone%20Teleop%20with%20ROSARIA/Android%20teleop%20Pioneer%203at) for step by step guide.

I hope the GPS works also.

---

Originally posted by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) with karma: 179 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-12-30**:
Its good, I will try it. But main problem is how to use Robot_localization package for pose estimation. Plz help me in that.

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2014-12-30**:
I usually use [Monte Carlo localization](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) for robot localization. Sorry, I never used  Robot_Localization package before. Actually, I don't believe that kalman filter is a good solution for non-linear estimation problems.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-12-30**:
It has a UKF as well.

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2014-12-30**:
Thanks Tom,
I will check the UKF. Is the pkg compatible with ROS fuerte?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-12-30**:
No, it was released after Fuerte was EOL'd, and so it was built to use `catkin`. However, you could potentially pull down the source and make it compatible with `rosbuild`. Not sure if all the dependencies will work.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-12-30**:
Tom Means Robot_localization is better than others. After Installation is there any need to change in code? or I can use directly? At this time I have IMU and Encoder counter which counts wheel rotations. I will check How can I use that. I am Using FirebirdVI from NEX Robotics. You can find details

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-12-31**:
Asan: Is  ROS ANdroid Sensor supportable in ROS HYDRO? I am using ROS Hydro with ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit.